# how to paginate and sort multiple querysets in same page?

Tags: django, django-views, django-pagination

I am using two query sets in one page and I want to have different paginations for each one

this is my class based view:

```
class MainListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    template_name = 'main.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MainListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['news'] = EventsPost.objects.all()
        context['posts'] = self.queryset
        return context
```

I want the Post model to be paginated by 3 and EventsPost by 6
Thanks for your responses

Comment: this is my home page and init i have to show the latest posts and events beside having individual pages for them. what if i use function base view? i don't get it actually

Comment: Do you actually need pagination (i.e. show page 2 of posts on the homepage). Or do you just want to show the latest 3 posts and 6 event posts? The second option is much simpler.

Comment: second option is literally what i want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't need pagination, I would use a `TemplateView`, and add the two querysets to the context in the `get_context_data` method.

```
class MainListView(TemplateView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MainListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['news'] = EventsPost.objects.order_by('-pk')[:6]
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.order_by('-pk')[:3]
        return context
```

If you want to sort on a different field, you could change it to something else e.g. `order_by('-date')`